# Cannot click on the content which is loaded through ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Currently, I cannot load the second content using ajax. Actually, I have loaded the first content using ajax. In order to go to the second content, i need to call the ajax function but after i click to load the second content using ajax it does not work. I have checked my code, its working fine if i directly call the second ajax function, unless i call the first ajax function after that the ajax is not working again. Are there any ways to solve this problem.

This is the first ajax code:

```
function showMusic(str) {
if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("albums").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("albums").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getAlbums.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
```

The above function works. The above function is at another php file

This is the second ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function showArtistDetails(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            alert("hi");
            document.getElementById("artist").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else { 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                            alert("hi1");

                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                            alert("hi2");

                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("artist").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                                alert("hi3");

                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","getArtist.php?title="+str,true);
                        alert("hi4");

            xmlhttp.send();
                        alert("hi5");

        }
    }

    $("#clickme").click(showArtistDetails);
});
```

This is the php code which is at another php file:

```
echo "<td id=\"clickme\">" . $row['CDTitle'] . "</td>";
```

I have been trying to solve this for the past 2 days but i am unable to solve it. Some are saying its a bug. But i really i dont know what causes this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'i need to call the ajax function but after i click to load the second content using ajax it does not work'
Is the button which you are supposed click in order to get the artist details appear on the first content (albums)? If so, where did you subscribe the button to the onclick event?

Comment: I have doubt actually... Actually if i have a ajax function at 1.php do i have to create my second ajax function at the 1.php too or i can create in different php file?

Comment: I don't quite remember how does it work with PHP but if you can reference both files then there shouldn't be a problem using separate files.

Comment: i think the problem is with the undefined value `    echo "<td value='".$row['CDTitle']."' onclick=\"alert(this.value)\" id=\"clickme\">" . $row['CDTitle'] . "</td>";
` I am getthing this as undefined. Can i know how to get the value of the td tag